# How do I save my image which is decoded from tfrecord after plotting a box on it using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

```py
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(camera_image)
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cmap)
title = camera_name
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

`plt.savefig()` doesn't work. The saved images are blank.

However `plt.show()` clearly shows me an image with bounding boxes

Comment: Try to put ‘savefig’ before ‘show’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example where I am saving the feature maps from the layer 1 block of the VGG16 model. Later I am loading the same image and plotting it.

I am saving the image using `plt.savefig()` and later loading the same image using `load_img()` and plotting it. You have to call `plt.savefig()` before the `plt.show()`.

**Code -**

```
# plot feature map of first conv layer for given image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import Model
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import expand_dims

# load the model
model = VGG16()

# redefine model to output right after the first hidden layer
model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[1].output)
model.summary()

# load the image with the required shape
img = load_img('bird.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))

# convert the image to an array
img = img_to_array(img)

# expand dimensions so that it represents a single 'sample'
img = expand_dims(img, axis=0)

# prepare the image (e.g. scale pixel values for the vgg)
img = preprocess_input(img)

# get feature map for first hidden layer
feature_maps = model.predict(img)

# plot all 64 maps in an 8x8 squares
square = 8
ix = 1
for _ in range(square):
    for _ in range(square):
        # specify subplot and turn of axis
        ax = pyplot.subplot(square, square, ix)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        # plot filter channel in grayscale
        pyplot.imshow(feature_maps[0, :, :, ix-1], cmap='gray')
        ix += 1

# save the figure
pyplot.savefig("Bird_Layer1")

# load the saved figure
img = load_img('Bird_Layer1.png')

# print the loaded figure
pyplot.show(img)
```

Output -

```
Model: "model_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_17 (InputLayer)        (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,792
Trainable params: 1,792
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Sruthi Kuriakose - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.